# Terminal Block Strip Electrical Block Connector 3A 5A 10 Amp /36 Wire Connectors min and max current limit?

Tags: connector

With reference to the picture below:

[image: package of three sizes of terminal strip]

The first block connector have a 3A shown beside, the second one with 5A and the third one have 10A.

What do the 3A, 5A and 10A mean?

Does it mean that the 3A can support a maximum of 3A current? Does the 5A support maximum of 5A current and a minimum of 3A current?

Answer (score 1):

Those ratings indicate that the smallest terminal block can safely carry up to 3 Amps on each terminal, the middle one can handle up to 5 Amps, and the largest, up to 10 Amps.

The terminals will over-heat if they are asked to carry more than the rated current.

Comment: Thanks but what happen for those without any current rating label?

Comment: The ratings shown on that package apply to the terminal blocks in that package.  For other terminal blocks, you will have to find the ratings from their manufacturer or seller (but I would guess that terminal blocks of similar sizes to those in your photo would have similar ratings)

Comment: If they don't have a rating label you get a choice : (1) rate them the same as another of the same size, or: (2) don't trust them.

Comment: There is also no minimum current. A larger one generally has lower resistance and thus lower losses than a smaller one. They are supposed to be able to carry any current up to the given value.